# How to get only updated row from database and make app more efficient

Tags: sql, database, laravel, vue.js

I'm creating laravel/vue.js CRUD app and I everything works fine for now but I'm worried about quality of my queries to database after update data.

I am using **getAllData()** each time when I update row in the database. Now, when I have a few records in database is not a problem to ask server each time and render new list in vue but in when I will have a few thousands of rows it will make my app slow and heavy.

Now I update database like this:

This is part of **my vue.js update function:**

```
updateStatus: function(id){

    var index = _.findIndex(this.rows,["id",id]);

    if (this.rows[index].pay_status=="waiting"){
       axios.put("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/payments/"+id
       ,{pay_status:"payed"}).then((response)=>{

       this.getAllData();         
}
```

This is  **my vue.js getAllData function:**

```
getAllData: function(){
        axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/payments").then((response)=>{         
        this.rows = response.data;
        });       
}
```

and my **PaymentsController:**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Payments;
use App\Suppliers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Faker\Generator;

class PaymentsController extends Controller
{
  public function index()
  {         
    $payments = Payments::with('suppliers')->get();
    return response($payments, Response::HTTP_OK);
  }
}
```

**my updation function:**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $payments = new Payments();
    payments::where('id', $id)->update($request->all());
}
```

Is thare any way to make update in more efficient way, for example get only updated row from database and put it into my existing object with rows? Or maybe i should not worried about it?

Comment: Show us the logic for the `api/payments/{id}` route from the controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your logic:

Your controller can return the record:

```
return response(['payment' => $payment], Response::HTTP_OK);
```

Your axios method can observe that response and then do a replace on the index (just like you did when getting the index previously)

```
.then((response) => {
    const { payment } = response.data;

    this.items[index] = payment;
})
```

As long as `items` was instantiated in `data` as an `[]` then it's observable.

Comment: Than you @Ohgodwhy. I forgot about logic of api/payments/{id} but now  I updated my post. Can you help me, make query properly?

Answer (score 0):

**If you need updated rows for particular time period.**

Also, you can do one thing. When user updating the row u can store the unique ID in new table and you can fetch the data through that ID. and then you can delete that ID from new table when you don't need latest updated data.

**WHILE UPDATING THE ROW via ID**

1. insert id in new table.
2. update the record.
3. if need updated record only >> use back-end conditions as per the
   requirement >> Fetch id from new table join with main table.
4. when you don't need that latest updated record. Delete records from
   new table.  >> use back-end conditions as per the requirement >>
   fetch from main table.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have an example of such a solution?

Comment: sorry I can't provide you the code. But you can follow the flow. from ans.(just edited.)

Answer (score 0):

As @Ohgodwhy said, I change my code like this and now it works fine.

**update function**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $payments = new Payments();
    payments::where('id', $id)->update($request->all());
    return response(payments::where('id', $id)->get(), Response::HTTP_OK);
}
```

**axios**

```
    updateStatus: function(id){

           var index = _.findIndex(this.rows,["id",id]);

            if (this.rows[index].pay_status=="oczekuje"){
                axios.put("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/payments/"+id,{pay_status:"zapłacono"}).then((response)=>{
                this.rows[index].pay_status=response.data[0].pay_status;
                this.waitingInvoices = this.countInvoices();
                this.toPay = this.calculatePayment();


            }); 
            } else if (this.rows[index].pay_status=="zapłacono"){
               axios.put("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/payments/"+id,{pay_status:"oczekuje"}).then((response)=>{
               this.rows[index].pay_status=response.data[0].pay_status;
               this.waitingInvoices = this.countInvoices();
               this.toPay = this.calculatePayment();

            }); 
            }
    },
```